# How to get data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have table (media) having 20 record with 5 columns (id,name,phone,email,address) 
i need to show this 20 records in my php file how to do this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Learn how to query a database using PHP](http://codular.com/php-mysqli), then get data from the database using a query like:

`SELECT * FROM media;`

Expanded solution:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM media;";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['id'] . ', ' . $row['name'] . ', ' . $row['phone'] . ', ' . $row['email'] . ', ' . $row['address'] . '<br />';
}
```

Each field will be available in the `$row` array for earch result row.

Comment: I know this query but i have problem to show this 20 record with mysqli_fetch_assoc function

Answer (score 0):

The best place to learn how to do this would be to read the manual or look on the [PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) but this should give you a headstart hopefully.

```
<?php
        $host='dbhost';
        $user='dbuser';
        $pass='dbpassword';
        $db='dbname';


        $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die( mysqli_error() );
        if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) die( 'Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error );



        $sql='select `id`,`name`,`phone`,`email`,`address` from `media`;';

        $res=$mysqli->query($sql);

        while( $rs = $res->fetch_object() ) {
            echo $rs->id, $rs->name, $rs->phone, $rs->email, $rs->address,' <br />';
        }

        $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database_name");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
 
$query = "SELECT * FROM media";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo $row['id'] . ', ' . $row['name'] . ', ' . $row['phone'] . ', ' . $row['email'] . ', ' . $row['address'] . '<br />';
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

try this