# How Fetch Array String From MySQL And PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some data in a MySQL database, in one table and one column like below:

```
|column|
|data1 |
|data2 |
```

1. How can this data be fetched from the database using this query?

   `SELECT id FROM table WHERE column IN ('data1','data2')`
2. How can variables be defined in this part so that the query can read an array of strings?

   `IN ('data1','data2')`

Comment: Your first question has answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917023/how-to-get-data-from-mysql-database

Comment: i dont think so! i want fetch diffrent data from one column not several column

Comment: Like you want to fetch data only from `ID` column?

Comment: no i can fetch several column like id,nam and ... but my question is how to initialized my proviso in query like array string. like -> ('data1','data2'); how to put this in my query whit variable

Comment: I assume this query `SELECT id FROM table WHERE column IN ('data1','data2')` for your understanding to add variables in it. `SELECT id FROM table WHERE column IN ('$data1','$data2')`. This is how you will add variables in it. and this is what you mean?

Comment: yes but here we will consider only tow variable; my data  maybe store in one or several data like: data1,data2 and... in one column as array string and i want to use them as one variable in the query so that the query can fetch data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

Use mysqli_ functions: [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/mysqli_connect), [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/mysqli_query), [mysqli_fetch_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php), etc. to connect and query the database. Then use [mysqli_bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add bound parameters to the query.

For the **first question**, `how fetch this data from database so that i can use it in this query:` there are multiple options:

1. Use mysqli_ functions: [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/mysqli_connect), [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/mysqli_query), [mysqli_fetch_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php), etc.
2. [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

*Note: the following examples use variables for the database connection values - these could be included from another file, set beforehand, set from the ini file (e.g. using *mysqli.default_host* and others for mysqli_ functions) etc. like this example:

```
$serverName = '127.0.0.1'; //MySQL database server running on the same machine
$userName = 'user';
$password = 'data';
$databaseName = 'sampleData';
```

**mysqli_ functions:**

Procedural style:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($databaseServer, $userName, $password, $databaseName);
$query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE column IN ('data1','data2')";
$ids = array(); //for use later on
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
    //fetch objects (or could use mysqli_fetch_array()
    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        $ids[] = $obj->id; //or use array_push()
    }
    /mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($connection );
```

Object-oriented style:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($databaseServer, $userName, $password, $databaseName);
$query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE column IN ('data1','data2')";
$ids = array(); //for use later on
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    //fetch objects (or could use fetch_array()
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $ids[] = $obj->id; //or use array_push()
    }
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

**PDO functions:**

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.$databaseServer.';port=3306;dbname='.$databaseName.';charset=UTF8;',$username,$password); 
$query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE column IN ('data1','data2')";
$ids = array(); //for use later on

foreach ($connection->query($query) as $row) {
        $ids[] = $obj->id; //or use array_push()
}
```

For your **second question** `how define variable in this part so that the query can read array string`, you could:

1. Use [implode()](http://php.net/implode) to join values:

   `$query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE column IN ('".implode("', '",$values).")";`
2. Add a bound parameter using [mysqli_bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) or [PDO's bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). The major benefit here is that you don't need to worry about adding the quotes around strings (and possibly escaping single quotes if you are delimiting your query with single quotes).

e.g. with PDO:

```
$params = array();
foreach ($values as $index=>$value) {
    $params[] = ':value'.$index;
}
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id FROM table WHERE column IN ('.implode(',',$params).')');

foreach ($values as $index=>$value) {
    $sth->bindParam(':value'.$index, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

1st question:
Search at google before asking, but there is the answer:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE column IN ('data1','data2')" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $data = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            array_push($data,$row['id']);
        }

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    echo $data;
```

I like to put them in all in a array because it is neat but you can change it by changing `array_push($data,$row['id']);` to something where it will loop through all the results of `$row['id']` .so use `$row['id']` when you use those results.

For the second question, if i understand, you want to make sql understand php array right? In that case you have implode the array:

`$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE column IN (".implode(',', $dataarray).")" ;`

**P.S.:** dont forget to put `'` into the string , so if u had `["data1","data2"]` then u have to:

```
$dataarray = array();
foreach($olddataarray as $value)
        {
            array_push($dataarray,"'".$olddataarray."'");

        }
```

Comment: you sure about this syntax?  ({implode(',', $dataarray})

Comment: if you want to be more precision you can do `$sql = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE column IN (".implode(',', $dataarray).")" ;`