# Display some data from row and column

Tags: php, fetch

I'm trying to display first and second result from table, so that user can see both results on *profil.php* and the date from last result. I created a view *vwresult* that has these fields

```
id | ide | name    | mark | date
---+-----+---------+------+-----------
1  | 1   | trickpd | 3    | 06.01.2018
1  | 2   | trickpd | 2    | 03.01.2018 
5  | 3   | trickpd | 4    | 08.01.2018
5  | 4   | trickpd | 6    | 02.01.2018
```

That is my table with current result, insert new data in table will show more results in view table.
This is my code

```
$tst = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM vwresult WHERE id=$ig AND name='trickpd' ORDER BY id, date desc"); 
$marks = [];
while($tstx = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tst)) {
    $marks[] = $tstx['mark'];
}
```

After that I get stuck, and can't show the results.
The goal is:

- to show *mark* 3 and 2 and *date* 06.01.2018 for *id* 1,
- and when user opens details for *id* 5 to see results the will see 4, and 6 and also a 08.01.2018

Please help. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Is it about displaying data or fetching data ? If you just want to fetch a few at a time, look into the MySQL keyword `LIMIT`. If you're asking about displaying the data, you need to show us some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data from mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917023/how-to-get-data-from-mysql-database)

Comment: You can learn how to do that here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [ide] => 16
            [name] => trickpd
            [mark] => 1.5
            [date] => 06.01.2018
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [ide] => 18
            [name] => trickpd
            [mark] => 2.0
            [date] => 04.01.2018
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [ide] => 21
            [name] => trickpd
            [mark] => 1.0
            [date] => 03.01.2018
        )

)
1

Comment: now i wont to display onyl from arra[0] mark and date and from array[2 ] only mark... thi is the code $tst = $prob->FETCH_ALL(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with displaying the data.. I even create a two query one to show all the data and second with limit 1,1 but after that on script it's showing random data, not first and second result like I wont.. I'm trying to display last two results and the last date of inserting the data..